# Convertir Array char a FILE pointer en C

Tags: c

Esto trabajando con la funcion de PEM_read_PrivateKey()

```
EVP_PKEY *PEM_read_PrivateKey(FILE *fp, EVP_PKEY **x,pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);
```

de OpenSSL y quiero pasar el primer argumento directamente con Array del archivo Key, por ejemplo.

```
char key[] = {0x33, 0x53, 0x73, 0x62, 0x4e, 0x52, 0x67, 0x54, 0x54, 0x69, 0x59, 0x57, 0x35, 0x36, 0x73, 0x5a}....
EVP_PKEY *PEM_read_PrivateKey(key, EVP_PKEY **x,pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrás que usar la *otra* familia de funciones, las `..._bio_...`

La estructura `BIO` proporcionada por *OpenSSL* te permite justamente eso, utilizar tus propias *abstracciones* de I/O.

En tu caso,

```
char key[] = { ... };
BIO *mem;

mem = BIO_new_mem_buf( key, TAMAÑO ); // ¡ Cuidado con strlen( ) si no hay 0 al final !

EVP_PKEY *PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey( mem, EVP_PKEY **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u );
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!